# How to fetch the data from different node from Firebase realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Java and Firebase Realtime Database. Currently, I'm doing a project where the user can track the host location when the user inserts a tracking ID. Hence, I need to fetch the data of the host location when the user inserts the correct id. Now I facing the problem of the program searching the database when the user inserted the tracking ID.

Here is my database result.
[image: Here is my database.]

Below are the way how I fetch my data to the program.

```js
 private void isTrackingID() {
        String userTrackingID = enterTracking.getText().toString().trim();

        //Long userTrackingIDNumber = Long.parseLong(userTrackingID);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Tracking ID = " + userTrackingID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID");

        Query query = reference.orderByChild("TrackingID/id").equalTo(userTrackingID);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                  Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

                   enterTracking.setError(null);

                   //String IDfromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child(userTrackingID).getValue(String.class);

                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       latitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("latitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                       longitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("HostLocation").child("longitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for longitude", longitudefromDatabase);
                       
                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

                      intent.putExtra("latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                      intent.putExtra("longitude", longitudefromDatabase);

                       startActivity(intent);

                   }
               }else {
                    enterTracking.setError("Invalid Tracking ID from database");
                    enterTracking.requestFocus();
                   }
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("error", databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

The program should get the host location when the user inserted the tracking ID. However, I keep receiving "Invalid Tracking ID from the database." when inserted the correct tracking id. So guys, where and how should I do the correction? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check my below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the following line of code:

```
Query query = reference.orderByChild("TrackingID/id").equalTo(userTrackingID);
```

Firebase Realtime Database queries can only return objects elements one level deeper in the tree. There is no way you can query such a database schema using a simple query. Besides that, there is a level (the UID perhaps) missing from your reference. So to be able to get all the tracking of all users where the "id" property holds that value of "444xxx", you might consider adding a new node in your database structure like so:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- tracking
        |
        --- id: "444xx"
        |
        --- uid: "loiJ ... OD53"
        |
        --- latitude: 1.858625
        |
        --- longitude: 103.0855767
```

In this way, you be able to get those elements using the following query:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference trackingRef = rootRef.child("tracking");
Query query = trackingRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(444xxx);
```

As you can see, if you need the user details, the UID is also present. The above practice is called denormalization and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. For a better understanding, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that needs to keep in mind. In the same way, you are adding data, you need to maintain it. In other words, if you want to update/delete an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I still not very clear about the fetching process for firebase. The program should search the id with hold 444xx inside the branch of  hostID.  So how we can let the program just get the data with id 444xx by just searching the 444xx in the brunch of hostID?

Comment: No, you cannot do that using your actual database schema. You cannot simply "search" the entire database using a key. You should get down in the tree, level by level in order to read the nested data. That's why you should create a new node that should contain only the data you need.

Comment: So I need to create a new node which contain the data i need only, then that function only? Is there have another way to search for two level data in firebase?

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended way in this case. You can search two-level deep but only if the children have fixed names. In your case, the UID is different for each child, as well as the tracking ID.

Comment: Alright, so now I create a new node with the data which I require in the searching process  then I can access the other data in different node, right?

Comment: Yes, you can. As long as you have enough data to build the reference, you'll always be able to access other nodes. For example, if you need the User's data, based on the UID that is present in the object, you can create another database call and get the corresponding data.

Comment: Sorry for the late response as I just complete getting the data using your explanation. The result was good and I was able to get the data. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good to hear that, and you're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

in your database node, you have Tracking and in query, you have added TrackingID
so just use Traking/id instead of TrakingID/id check the code below.

```
Query query = reference.orderByChild("TrackingID/id").equalTo(userTrackingID);



Query query = reference.orderByChild("Tracking/id").equalTo(userTrackingID);
```

Comment: This method can get the data or not? In my case, I cannot get the data and keep showing the invalid Tracking ID. Hence the query cannot fetch the data with two level deep without a clear  reference.

Comment: It will return the data. Have tried with change? if yes then send the code snippet again with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my code:

```
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            reference.child("Users").orderByChild("phone").equalTo(number)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {
                                        UserData userData = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserData.class);
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(container.getContext(), UserDetailActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("userData", userData);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(container.getContext(), "This mobile is not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
```

[image: this is my database structure. I am also fetching two level]